# Using Graphite, how can I display a series of charts that all share the same yMax?

Tags: graphite

Graphite has a [render API](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/render_api.html) that allows an app to request a chart, with specific attributes: colors, legend or not, title, data on the chart, and so on.  One thing that can be varied is the y-axis limits (yMin and yMax).

I'd like to display 4 charts, all with the same data, but over different time intervals. I want the yaxis to be the same on each of the 4 charts.  If I don't specify the yMax, then the yMax gets chosen automatically by Graphite, and it gets chosen to a different value for each chart:

[image]

You can see the ymax ranges from 300 to 400.  It makes the charts hard to compare. What I want is this:

[image]

I can explicitly set the yMax, but ... how do I choose the right value?  The only way I can see to do this now is to query all the raw data, then compute the yMax, then actually use the computed yMax in the render UI.

This works but querying the raw data is REALLY EXPENSIVE and ships a ton of json.  Has anyone figured out a way to avoid this?  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was the way I described: 
query the raw data, compute the max, then in a callback, request charts with yMax set to that value.